# Why does this time fail to be parsed by DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()?

Tags: java, java-8, localtime

When I run the following:

```
String s2 = "07:05:45PM";
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(s2, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ssa"));
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
Text '07:05:45PM' could not be parsed at index 8
```

It seems to not like the AM/PM designator, but as far as I find, this should work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What locale are you running this in? Since your code doesn't specify a locale it will use the default locale of your JVM (which in turn will be taken from the default of your current user or machine). Also `HH` is meant for 24h clocks, you'll want to use `hh` if you want to include `a` as well.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I needed to use 'h' AND specify a locale that allows for this parsing. (NOTE, my default locale is 'en-GB')

    String s2 = "07:05:45PM";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime
        .parse(s2, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa").withLocale(Locale.US));
    return time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);

Comment: I must question the decision of moderators to voted to close this question as duplicate before any answers were accepted. The referenced question makes no reference to the running locale, which was the critical detail in this instance.

Answer (score 6):

You are using a specifier for 24 hour format (and saying AM there at 0700). Use `hh` instead of `HH`. Like,

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(s2, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa"));
```

Comment: Wondered why that would be a problem... Checked `LocalTime.parse("16:12PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mma"))`, and it parses. But `"04:12PM"` as input fails with the exception. Worse, `LocalTime.of(16,3,3).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mma"))` doesn't crash. I'm failing to find logic (or at least consistency) in this validation.

Comment: Your "worse" example invokes no **parsing** (just formatting). Your first example is exactly like this question.

Comment: @ernest_k: I think the logic is quite clar: 16 on the 24h clock and PM don't contradict each other. 04 on the 24h clock and PM do contradict each other. Internally consistent data for a weird, but valid pattern is accepted. Internally conflicting data for the same pattern is rejected. Seems sensible. In a similar way "Sunday, 26. 2. 2020" is not a valid date, but "Wednesday, 26. 2. 2020" is.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Makes sense, thanks. I guess I kinda didn't find a justification for the tolerated redundancy, but I see the API doesn't allow it to break the information. Thanks

Comment: @ernest_k: there's many date format that include unnecessary redundancy (basically every date format that includes a day of the week, for example). Not supporting them would be a major flaw.

Comment: Using lower case 'h' also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using a capital `H`, which describes an hour of the 24-hours notation and causes a mismatch between `07` and `PM`.

Do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    String time = "07:05:45PM";
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa"));

    System.out.println(localTime.toString());
}
```

The output is

```
19:05:45
```

Comment: l tried using lower case h and that also doesn't work.

Comment: @ThatDataGuy what was wrong? Did you get the same `Exception`?

Comment: The same exception

Comment: @ThatDataGuy Have you tried to parse different time `String`s? The one you provided was not parseable at all because `07` and `PM` only work with a lower `h`. Does it work without the `PM` or with an `AM` instead?

Comment: It was due to my locale - see my comment on the question.

Comment: @ThatDataGuy yes, I have already read it... You can also try to use `withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)` to be independent from countries or regions, it only depends on the language.